# Feof дублирование последней строчки

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Как сделать так что бы функция не дублировала последнюю строчку при считывании файла.
Вот вам код

```
void userDELL()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char log1[100], pass1[100], log_f1[100], pass_f1[100], log_f2, pass_f2[100];
    text = fopen("user.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(text))
    {
        fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1);
        printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feof()` возвращает истину только после того, как случилась попытка чтения за его концом. Что у вас происходит: последняя `fscanf()` читает последнюю строку, но *чтения за концом файла* пока ещё не было. Поэтому цикл выполнится ещё раз. На этот раз `fscanf()` ничего не прочитает, но вы ж не проверяете её возврат, вот и выводите старые значения переменных снова.

```
while( fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1) == 2 )
{
    printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
}
```

И никакая `feof()` не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

`feof` устанавливается в `true` при первой попытки чтения после конца файла. Есть 2 варианта, или сначала читать, потом проверять конец файла (этот метод существенно завит от наличия/отсутствия в конце файла пробельных символов); или проверять результат `fsanf` возвращает количество прочитанных байт или -1, если чтение не удалось.

```
    while (fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1) != -1)
       printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
```

Comment: "*fsanf возвращает количество прочитанных байт*" - не-а :) Это `fread()` так делает.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while (!feof(text))
> {
>     fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1);
>     printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
> }
> ```

Баг можно было бы исправить так:

```
while (1)
{
  fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1);
  if (feof(text)) break;
  printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
}
```

или так:

```
while (fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1), !feof(text))
  printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
```

Но правильно сделать так:

```
while (fscanf(text, "%s\t%s", log_f1, pass_f1) == 2)
  printf("%s\n %s\n", log_f1, pass_f1);
```

---

Хм.. Что-то я засомневался про вариант с перемещением проверки на feof. Возможно, он будет зависеть от завершающего перевода строки.

Впрочем, кажется, можно поставить пробел в конце формата и вернуться к твоему варианту.

В общем, надо не пользоваться feof, а проверять, что вернул scanf.

Ну и ещё. Такое использование `\t` в формате совершенно бессмысленно. сам `%s` пропустит все пробельные символы. Если ты хотечь прочитать всё после табуляций (в любом количестве) до конца строки, используй `%[^\r\n]`.